# Arduino Mega ADK and Itead Bluetooth Shield V2.2 can't get AT commands to work

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, at-command

I am using the Arduino Mega ADK chip with the Itead Bluetooth shield V2.2 and Arduino 1.01 software and I cannot figure out how to get the AT command to return 'OK' from the Arduino serial monitor.

I have the bluetooth chip setup for cmd where the rx is on D0 and tx is on D1 and switch is in cmd mode, just as the manual shows it should be configured for cmd. (See link below)

http://iteadstudio.com/store/images/produce/Shield/BTshieldv2.2/BTShieldV2.2_DS.pdf

I then tried an application on the chip such as blink where there is no serial commands involved and when I open the serial monitor I am able to enter in commands but receive no response. I attempt every type of baud of the monitor as well.

I am planning on using the Amarino application to control the bluetooth chip, but I cannot find any assistance on getting these commands to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I still could not get the serial monitor to return any values so I decided to use tera term, which worked a MILLION times easier and made it simple to change the configurations on my Bluetooth chip.